# Wrong orientation on Tablet running ubuntu 18.10

Tags: display, display-rotation, orientation

Have ubuntu 18.10 installed on a nuvision  TM800W610L tablet. The accelerometer seems to be working as the desktop rotates when I rotate the tablet but the orientation is off. Holding it upright (vertical) makes the desktop tilt horizontal and vice versa. My only guess is it has to do with the iio-sensors? Anyone have any idea how to fix the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem with similar hardware under Debian right now. Ubuntu shouldn't be much different.

As a short-term temporary solution, open a terminal and type "`xrandr -o right`". This will help you started.

For the long term, you need to find a transformation matrix for your orientation sensor and somehow have it recognized by the system. Track to follow is systemd-udev events and custom hwdb. Look for "`60-sensor.hwdb`" in https://github.com/systemd/systemd and start from there.

That's the solution that makes most sense to me, but I haven't been able to glue all the pieces together yet ;-)